# delete user and clicking backward

Tags: flutter, dart

if i have a button to delete user and when the admin click delete it deleted successfully but if the user clicks backward button return the admin to a user who was deleted. so i tried to do this code:

```
 onPressed: () => {
 {
   c = 0,
   Navigator.of(
    context)
     .popUntil(
      (_) =>
        c++ >=
         3),
         },
```

this return the admin to user list but the problem its contains the user who was deleted:>
so what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you refreshing a list with users that contains deleted user?